# Nested containers: why cant i access the stack at the top of a queue of stack? C++

Tags: c++, stack, containers

So i have created a queue of stacks using the STL as follows:

```
void main()
{
    queue<stack<string>> qos;
    stack<string> words;
    words.push("hey");
    qos.push(wors);
    cout<< (qos.pop()).top()<<endl;
}
```

**Expected behavior:**

returns the word ***hey***

**Actual result:**

error: member reference base type 'void' is not a structure or union

My question is why doesn't it return what i was expecting, i mean since qos.pop() returns stack element and stack has the member function top();

Comment: pop() doesn't return anything - have you tried reading the documentation?

Comment: And BTW `void main()` is wrong also, it should be at least `int main()`.

Comment: Your're right, i thought this worked the same way as java. I guess its time i face the consequences of posting a stupid question on stackoverflow and get dislikes.

Comment: There aren't any "dislikes" here.

Comment: down-votes or whatever they are. anyways thanks for pointing clarifying what i have done wrong before they put my question down for good.

Answer (score -1):

Your variables `words` and `qos` are not related in any way.

Also `main()` must have a return type of `int`.

The reason for the error message you get is, that `queue<>::pop` does not return a value `top()` could be called upon.

You probably want

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::queue<std::stack<std::string>> qos;
    std::stack<std::string> words;

    words.push("hey");
    qos.push(words);

    std::cout << qos.front().top() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to add the line of code that appends words to the queue here,

Comment: It doesn't matter  what the return value of main is about as that isn't what the question about! suppose this statement is inside a function other than the main function :)

Comment: @OneMilli "suppose this statement is inside a function other than the main function :)" there IS a function `main()` returning `void` in OPs sample code. The standard clearly states "Its type shall have C++ language linkage and it shall have a declared return type of type int, [...]". So OPs sample is not a valid C++-program and could be anything.

Comment: All true, but that doesn't answer the question. The reason for the error simply is that `pop()` doesn't return the top value removed from the stack.